# How to Sum specific sections of a 2d array?

Tags: java, arrays, sum

I can't get my array to sum up specific portions.

This is the instruction for my program:

Write a program to prepare company sales report
• The program asks the user to input the daily sales of three products for one week. Use
double 2D array for the 3 products and 7 days.
• Display the sales of each product .
Then, the program calculates and displays the following:
• Sales total of all three products for one week.
• Daily average sales of all products.
• Sales total of each product for one week. Use 1D array to save the total sales of each product.
• Daily Average sales of each product.
• Sales total of all products of the weekend (assuming that the sixth and seventh
days are Saturday and Sunday respectively)
• Average of weekend sales.

This is what I have coded:

```
*import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;
public class AprilSales {
 public static void main (String[] args){ 
    Scanner scnr=new Scanner(System.in);
     int [] days={1, 2, 3, 4 , 5, 6, 7};
     int p[] product={1, 2, 3};
    double sales1[][]=new double[1][7];
    
      for(int i=0;i< sales.length;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<sales[0].length;j++){
            System.out.print("Enter the sales of Product " + product[i] + " on day " 
            + days[j] + ": ");
            sales[i][j] = scnr.nextDouble();
        }
         System.out.print("\n");
    }

    //DISPLAY
    System.out.println("Display the sales of each product: " +       "\n");
    //DISPLAY
    for(int i=0;i< sales.length;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<sales[0].length;j++){
            System.out.print("The sales of Product " +  product[i] + " on day " + 
            days[j] + ": $" +sales[i][j] + "\n");

        }
         System.out.print("\n");
    }
   
           
    //SUM//
      
     
    for(int i=0;i<sales3.length;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<sales3.length;j++){
         System.out.println("Sales total of all products for one week: $"
        + sales3 );
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Sales total of all products for one week: $" + sales3);
    
    double sum=0;
    for(int i=0;i<sales1.length;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<sales1[0].length;j++){
        sum=sum +sales1[i][j];
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Sales total of product 1: $" + sum); 
    
    
    for(int i=0;i<sales2.length;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<sales2[0].length;j++){
        sum=sum +sales2[i][j];
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Sales total of product 2: $" + sum); 
}*
```

Comment: You are declaring seperate arrays for sale1 sale 2 and sale 3 with size 1*7 which essentially makes it 1d array. Just declare one array 'sales[3][7]'

Comment: I see. So I did fix it.

Answer (score 0):

## Sales total of each product for one week

```
int sums = new int[product.length];
for (int i = 0; i < product.length; i++) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < sales[i].length; j++) sum += sales[i][j];
    System.out.println("Sales total for product " + product[i] + " was " + sum);
    sums[i] = sum;
}
```

In the above:

- we create a 1d array for `sums` as the specification asks us to do
- we loop the products
- and for each product we loop the days
- and for each day we add the value to `sum`
- display the situation
- store the sum in the 1d array

## Daily Average sales of each product

```
for (int i = 0; i < sales[0].length; i++) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < product.length; j++) {
        sum += sales[i][j];
    }
    double avg = sum / product.length;
    System.out.println("Average for day " + i + " was " + avg);
}
```

In the above

- we calculate the sum for each day
- divide it with the number of products to get the average
- display the result

## Sales total and average for the weekend

```
int totalW = 0;
int avgW = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < product.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 6; j <= 7; j++) {
        totalW += sales[i][j];
    }
}
avgW = totalW / 2; //Assuming that we need to get the daily average for the weekend including all 3 products
System.out.println("Weekend sales were " + totalW + " and weekend averages were " + avgW);
```